# Zooming in on hexagon tiles javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

I created a [hexagon grid map](http://jsfiddle.net/CharCoding/11Lagwye/) and needed to be able to zoom in. The wheel event zooming in was added correctly, but when I zoom in, the top/left side of the map is covered and I can't scroll to the very top/left (bottom/right sides are reachable).

Likewise, if I zoom out, there is a huge gap on the top/left sides, while the bottom/right sides are normal. I'm not sure why this happens but I can't fix it.

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#map {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px 1px;
  width: 3032px;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: visible;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
body {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#map>div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34.64px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border-left: solid 1px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.8);
  border-right: solid 1px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.8);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 400ms;
}
#map>div:nth-child(97n+50) {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
#map>div:before,
#map>div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 42.43px;
  height: 42.43px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 7.7868px;
}
#map>div:before {
  top: -21.2132px;
  border-top: solid 1.4142px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.8);
  border-right: solid 1.4142px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.8);
}
#map>div:after {
  bottom: -21.2132px;
  border-bottom: solid 1.4142px #333333;
  border-left: solid 1.4142px #333333;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
for (var j = 0; j < 2500; j++) {
  var tile = document.createElement('div');
  tile.setAttribute('id', '#' + j);
  tile.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
  map.appendChild(tile);
}
var zoom = 1;
document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  //console.log((map.scrollLeft + e.pageX) + ' ' + (map.scrollTop + e.pageY));
  map.style.transformOrigin = (map.scrollLeft + e.pageX) + 'px ' + (map.scrollTop + e.pageY) + 'px';
  // This is so that the zoom center is at the cursor. (I feel like this is causing the problem)
  zoom += e.deltaY / 5;
  if (zoom < 0.5) zoom = 0.5;
  else if (zoom > 5) zoom = 5;
  console.log(map.style.transform = "scale(" + zoom + ")");
}, false);
```

It seems that some browsers don't provide support for arrow keys navigation in this case. I'm using Firefox and arrow key navigation works.

Can someone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really fix it, but I do have a suggestion. When zooming, you set a transform-origin based on the current position on the map. However, when changing the position by scrolling, you do not re-calculate that transform-origin. After having scrolled back to the top-left the transform-origin is not 0 0 that I think it should be.

So it's probably an idea to put the calculations inside a named function and attach event handlers for scroll and key input.

A quick test in FF shows that the map, after zooming, does go to top-left after keypress (obviously the changed code is flawed and the zoom stops working after keypress).

http://jsfiddle.net/11Lagwye/1/

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', myfunc, false);
document.addEventListener('keydown', myfunc, false);

function myfunc(e) {
// your zoom.transform code
}
```